# Installing a garden hose to a threaded valve, but not enough space

Tags: valve, plumbing-fixture, hose

I'm trying to attach a garden hose to a valve with an outer diameter of 1", but there is not enough vertical clearance to attach the hose.
What would be the best way to make a connection in this case?

I believe a kind of "male-to-female" pipe connector with a 90 degree bend is required, but am unsure of the correct terminology / specifications when looking for one.

For clarification, below is a picture of the valve and the hose.

[image: 3/4" threaded valve]

[image: hose]

The top part of the hose, when detached, fits into the valve as shown below.
[image: top part of hose fits into valve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the most readily-available solution was a swivel hose connector associated with gardening supplies (thanks to the hint from @*PennyPincherWannaBeHandyMan* 's answer), of which Walmart lists as an "Expert Gardener Metal Hose Swivel Connector".

It is like an elbow connector from @*Jack* 's answer, but has a flexible top part that allows it to screw into the faucet so that space constraints are less of a problem.

[image: Swivel hose connector]

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself an elbow that you can add to the faucet to have better access.

Photo courtesy Home Depot

[image]

Comment: Google searching that image shows a Home Depot listing of a "3/4 in. MHT x 3/4 in. FHT Lead-Free Brass Garden Hose 90-Degree Elbow Fitting". However, my faucet's (the part the elbow's male hose thread connects to) outer diameter is 1". Does that mean that the MHT of the elbow fitting must be 1"?

Comment: The size may be 1" outside dimension, but the pipe size goes by inside dimension of 3/4" .I think the MHT is Male Hose Thread and  the FHT is Female Hose Thread.... Specific to garden hoses.

Answer (score 1):

You could purchase a kink free hose connector. Any super store or home improvement store has them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding a picture would be very helpful here.